# Saving a file inside app's main directory

Tags: ios, xcode

txt file under App.app/here.text ?
Currently I found `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`

```
 NSArray* dirs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject] error:NULL];
```

but it places under documents. Can i save it under under Appname.app/here

https://www.alphansotech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/iosDirectory.png

in what level i can list read files?
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF4585FC-743D-409D-83A9-B8A298D44C74/App.app

```
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
  [path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
  NSArray* dirs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] error:NULL];
  NSLog(@"sss..%@",path );

  NSLog(@"sss..%@",[path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]);

  NSString *stringToWrite = @"1\n2\n3\n4";
  NSString *filePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"main.jsbundle"];

  [stringToWrite writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
  
  [dirs enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
      NSLog(@"sss...%@", obj);
  }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short:

No, you can't. For obvious reasons it's impossible to write into the application bundle.

Comment: No, you can't. Writing into the application bundle invalidates the code signature.

Comment: can i rewrte a file same level as App folder? so one step up of those, documents level

Comment: No, you can write files only into the application **container** and even there only into specific folders.

Comment: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D42BEFF-FE20-4A31-A939-EDC3648D69E8/App.app what leel i can write here? i cant list folders at application dir.

Comment: What part of *you can't* is unclear? Write your custom files into the `Documents` or `Application Support` folder.

Comment: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/838F546B-EC2C-4A65-BBC2-40FE408DAF66/Documents/myfile.txt data folder you mean, bundle is not writeable

Answer (score -1):

Find the resources path :

```
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
path            = [path stringByAddingPathComponent:@"myFileName.myExtension"];
```

To simply get the file you can use :

```
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFileName" ofType:@"myExtension"];
```

Note however that it's not recommended to save files within the application bundle especially because of code signature.

Comment: ./Users/xxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BB4BCA21-7A1D-4444-8422-CD13185334F1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BD2F18D5-7BB6-425A-B9BC-8E9FC9D5C29F/App.app , tthis is resource path i think i need to write under here

Comment: I though that the IOS bundle has the same anatomy than on MacOS, but it isn't, sorry. Apparently all is at the first level so, yes, you can see it as the resources directory (but the binary is there too : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1). I edited my answer.

Comment: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF4585FC-743D-409D-83A9-B8A298D44C74/App.app,,, some other app did write into app.app i unzipped and saw images and custom files